# Datasets vs Sql Queries (select, procedure, function) Which is better to use?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, dataset

I currently use SQL queries (select, procedures, functions) for communication with database.

Till now I have not used Dataset. I really can't get the concept of dataset. I just know that they can be used to select, insert, update, or delete from database too.

But why would be even need a dataset, when we can use the SQL commands to do the same tasks.

Is dataset better in terms of security? Or is it faster?

Update:

So I read this forum ashutosh gave
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/100cce91-cf9c-46c9-986a-98a409a196f2

> DataSet on the other side can be created from designer. Designer allows you to create tables, relations, contraints,... Drag and drop from Server Explorer might be another benefit. With DataAdpater you can create a typed DataSet upon the queries. If you're application requires import/export, you'll have to write this functionality on your own when using custom entities. With DataSet this ain't a problem, allowing you to import/export data into XML. It can also be bound to DataGridView or any other similar control. DataSet also supports one level of history, allowing you to revert to previous version of each row.

Quite helpful, But still question persists, should I use Datasets or queries to handle database. Like editing records, updating, deleting and such.

I use my queries like:

```
    SqlCommand cmdCheck = default(SqlCommand);
    string strQry ="Update, Delete, Insert queries";

    cmdCheck = new SqlCommand(strQry, Connection);
    openConnection();
    cmdCheck.ExecuteCommand();
    CloseConnection();
```

and DataAdapter For select queries.

Comment: you mean you are using `ADODB` or `ADO.Net`?

Comment: DataSets are the old technique for accessing a database. I recommend against using them unless you're stuck at .NET 2.0. Use Entity Framework instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not any good answer till now. :(

So I would think it is better to use queries than Datasets.
because
- Datasets can be difficicult to manage for large datas. I think they may cause slow data transfers.
- the Sql queries are short and simple to write.
- I know sql queries better because i have not used datasets till now.

If i am wrong do reply with resonable answers.

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries work better and more granular than DataSets. DataSets are a simplification of a table interface, which usually results in too much data from poorly designed tables. A further abstraction of relational databases and standard query language is the concept of ORMs like Hibernate and Microsoft's Entity Framework.

Yes, they make coding simple, but like all things simple, they take away the fine grained approach to database design and normalisation, as well as good coding practise and skills.

Answer (score 1):

A reading of the following link should clear it out.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetdataset/thread/100cce91-cf9c-46c9-986a-98a409a196f2

The idea is not just to talk to a database. Dataset has features which help you do stuff after you comeback from the database. Having strongly typed sets helps, e.g. you will have the ability to bind to controls in the user interface.